# How to use CSS variable in same rule that declares it

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, css-variables

In my custom element's definition, I have the following code:

```
<dom-module id="dom-element">
  <style>
    p {
      --test: brown;
      color: var(--test);
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <p>I'm a DOM element. This is my local DOM!</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "dom-element"
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

However, the CSS custom property isn't working. Polymer just turns this:

```
p {
  --test: brown;
  color: var(--test);
}
```

into this:

```
p {
  color: ;
}
```

But I want the output to be:

```
p {
  color: brown;
}
```

The demo can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ogMVPKNvc7SYISomWPWm?p=preview

If I don't use Polymer, and create the custom element in pure JavaScript, the CSS custom property works as expected.

I have searched Google, but didn't find something related. What's the problem here? How can I use the CSS custom property with Polymer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer 1's CSS shim (enabled by default) apparently doesn't handle the CSS variable declaration in the same rule that uses it, so you'd have to move the declaration to `:host` in this scenario.

```
<!-- inside dom-module's template -->
<style>
  :host {
    --test: brown;
  }
  p {
    color: var(--test);
  }
</style>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          --test: brown;
        }
        p {
          color: var(--test);
        }
      </style>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

However, you can enable native CSS properties in Polymer with a [global setting (`useNativeCSSProperties`)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings) declared before importing `polymer.html`, which would allow your code to work as-is:

```
<script>window.Polymer = {lazyRegister: true, useNativeCSSProperties: true};</script>
<!-- import polymer.html here -->
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script>window.Polymer = {dom: 'shadow', lazyRegister: 'max', useNativeCSSProperties: true};</script>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        p {
          --test: brown;
          color: var(--test);
        }
      </style>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bgzJgE?editors=1010)